# Plot a density differential semantic dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I'm coming here because after hours of research and failed trials, i dont know what to do next.

I've a database (opened via `dyplr` with the open_excel command) that looks like the one below (but more complexe with more variables) :

```
> dput(open)
structure(list(Subject = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), `Happy - Before` = c(4, 
4, 2, 1, 7), `Courageous - Before` = c(5, 2, 1, 3, 4), `Strange - Before` = c(1, 
2, 1, 4, 6), `Happy - After` = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2), `Courageous - After` = c(7, 
1, 5, 1, 2), `Strange - After` = c(3, 7, 4, 5, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Subject `Happy - Before` `Courageous - B… `Strange - Befo… `Happy - After`
    <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
1       1                4                5                1               4
2       2                4                2                2               2
3       3                2                1                1               6
4       4                1                3                4               2
5       5                7                4                6               2
# … with 2 more variables: `Courageous - After` <dbl>, `Strange - After` <dbl>
```

My goal here is to plot a density graph with some specificity :

[Density of scores obtained by all the subjects for each ability trait on a scale from 1 to 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHdcV.png)

As you can see on my (awful) graph, i'm trying to display the responses of all my subjects on a scale from 1 to 7 (x axis) via a density plot, but for each trait i have (y - axis), and thus, with a separation from responses made before [a test] and after a test. And i need to get the same kind of legend (courageous shown to the left, not courageous shown to the right). The more a participant is close to 7 when he answer to the scale, the more he is [happy, courageous, depressed, anxious....] and the more he get close to 1, the more he is [not happy, not courageous, not depressed...]
I tried my best (using `ggplot2` templates, trying to melt things and all but i fairly new to R and language programming :/)
All my variables have thos kind of name : `[trait1]_before`, `[trait2]_before`, `[trait1]_After`, `[trait2]_After`

I hope this post is clear. If not, i will be glad to add informations !
Thank you everyone (sorry for my pooor english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A density plot assumes a continuous variable along the x axis, whereas your example only goes from 1 to 7. This means you can plot the density where you will have tails that go past 0 and 7 or force a cut-off at those values.

```
data <- structure(list(Subject = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   `Happy - Before` = c(4, 4, 2, 1, 7),
                   `Courageous - Before` = c(5, 2, 1, 3, 4),
                   `Strange - Before` = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 6),
                   `Happy - After` = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2),
                   `Courageous - After` = c(7, 1, 5, 1, 2),
                   `Strange - After` = c(3, 7, 4, 5, 4)),
              row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

dataPivot <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Subject, names_to = "measure", values_to = "score") %>% 
  mutate(status = sub(".* - ", "", measure),
         feature = sub(" - .*", "", measure),
         featureOpposite = paste('Not', feature)) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
```

If you want to not truncate the plot:

```
# Create the first plot with the axis on the left
p1 <- ggplot(dataTest, aes(x = score, y = feature)) +
  geom_density_ridges2(aes(fill = status), scale = 0.7, alpha = .3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 7)) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme_ridges() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# Create a second plot with the legend on the right
p2 <- ggplot(dataTest, aes(x = score, y = featureOpposite)) +
  geom_density_ridges2(aes(fill = status), scale = 0.7, alpha = .3) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  theme_ridges() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# Convert both plots to gtables
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

# Add an empty column to the left side of the first plot to make room for the right
# axis
g1 <- gtable_add_cols(g1, widths = unit(0.2, "null"), pos = -1)

# overlap the panel of the 2nd plot on that of the 1st plot
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name == "axis-r", se = t:r))

# Add the y-axis from the second plot
g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name == "axis-r")]], pp$t, pp$r, 
  pp$b, pp$r)

grid.draw(g)
```

If you want to truncate the ends:

```
# Here we are just adding in a height variable, changing stat to density and adding
# trim = T
p1 <- ggplot(dataTest, aes(x = score, y = feature, height = ..density..)) +
  geom_density_ridges2(aes(fill = status), scale = 0.7, alpha = .3, stat = "density", 
  trim = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 7)) +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme_ridges() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

p2 <- ggplot(dataTest, aes(x = score, y = featureOpposite, height = ..density..)) +
  geom_density_ridges2(aes(fill = status), scale = 0.7, alpha = .3, stat = "density",             
  trim = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
  theme_ridges() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
g2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))

g1 <- gtable_add_cols(g1, widths = unit(0.2, "null"), pos = -1)

## overlap the panel of the 2nd plot on that of the 1st plot
pp <- c(subset(g1$layout, name=="axis-r", se=t:r))

g <- gtable_add_grob(g1, g2$grobs[[which(g2$layout$name=="axis-r")]], pp$t, pp$r, 
  pp$b, pp$r)

grid.draw(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder (as also hinted by @Amanda) whether a density plot is appropriate for this kind of data, but leaving this to the side, here's a shorter version that does not attempt to massage the data like @Amanda.

You can play around with the `bw` for different bandwidth selection methods (the default, `nrd0` is generally not recommended for non-Gaussian distributions as it tends to over-smooth).

```r
library(tidyverse)

open_long <- open %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Subject, names_to = c("state", "time"), names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+) - ([A-Za-z]+)")

ggplot(open_long, aes(x = value, fill = time)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5, bw = "SJ") +
  facet_wrap(~state, ncol = 1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>